# My NFC app stop auomatically

Tags: android, android-intent, nfc

I am a beginner of android application development. Currently I am trying to create an app which will launch after sensing the NFC tag, then it will read the tag the display the message in text view. It seems some problems exists causing my program stop unexpectedly.

Here is my java file:

```
public class Reader extends Activity {

TextView mText;
NfcAdapter mAdapter;
PendingIntent mPendingIntent;
IntentFilter mFilters[];
String mTechLists[][];

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_reader);

    mText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text);

    mAdapter = NfcAdapter.getDefaultAdapter(this);
    mPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,
            new Intent(this, getClass()).addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP), 0);

    IntentFilter ndef = new IntentFilter(NfcAdapter.ACTION_NDEF_DISCOVERED);
    try{
        ndef.addDataType("text/plain");
    }catch(MalformedMimeTypeException e){
        throw new RuntimeException("fail", e);
    }

    IntentFilter nt = new IntentFilter(NfcAdapter.ACTION_TAG_DISCOVERED);
    mFilters = new IntentFilter[]{
            ndef, nt
    };

    mTechLists = new String[][]{
            new String[]{
                    Ndef.class.getName()
            }
    };
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    mText.setText(getNdefMessages(intent));
}

public String getNdefMessages(Intent intent){
    NdefMessage[] msgs = null;
    String action = intent.getAction();
    if(NfcAdapter.ACTION_NDEF_DISCOVERED.equals(action)){
        Parcelable[] rawMsgs = intent.getParcelableArrayExtra(NfcAdapter.EXTRA_NDEF_MESSAGES);
        if(rawMsgs != null){
            msgs = new NdefMessage[rawMsgs.length];
            for(int i=0; i<rawMsgs.length; i++){
                msgs[i] = (NdefMessage) rawMsgs[i];
            }
        }else{
            byte[] empty = new byte[]{};
            NdefRecord record = new NdefRecord(NdefRecord.TNF_UNKNOWN, empty, empty, empty);
            NdefMessage msg = new NdefMessage(new NdefRecord[]{record});
            msgs = new NdefMessage[]{msg};
        }

    }
    else {
        finish();
    }
    return msgs.toString();
}

@Override
public void onResume(){
    super.onResume();
    mAdapter.enableForegroundDispatch(this, mPendingIntent, mFilters, mTechLists);
}

@Override
public void onPause(){
    super.onPause();
    mAdapter.disableForegroundDispatch(this);
}

@Override
public void onNewIntent(Intent intent){
    Log.i("Foreground dispatch", "Discovered tag with intent:" + intent);
    mText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text);
    mText.setText(getNdefMessages(intent));
}

}
```

And below is the AndroidManifest file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="android.reader"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0">

<uses-sdk 
    android:minSdkVersion="10" 
    android:targetSdkVersion="15" />

<uses-permission 
    android:name="android.permission.NFC"/>

<uses-feature 
    android:name="android.hardware.nfc"
    android:required="true"/>

<application android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
    android:debuggable="true">
    <activity 
        android:name=".Reader"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_reader">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.nfc.action.NDEF_DISCOVERED"/>
            <data 
                android:scheme="http"
                android:host="developer.android.com"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.nfc.action.TAG_DISCOVERED"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

</application>

</manifest>
```

The tag I use to test is containing an url record. Can anyone give a hand to me?

Comment: Could you post the output of logcat?

Comment: I first discover there is a version problem, so I change it a little bit, however, there still has error,
here is the message show in the console:
[2012-07-10 15:02:17 - Reader] Starting activity android.reader.Reader on device 0146AFFC0300601C
[2012-07-10 15:02:17 - Reader] ActivityManager: Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] cmp=android.reader/.Reader }

Comment: And following are the messages show in the logcat, I will seperate them in a few commands:07-10 15:02:15.769: W/dalvikvm(3030): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a2b1f8)
07-10 15:02:15.769: E/AndroidRuntime(3030): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-10 15:02:15.769: E/AndroidRuntime(3030): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{android.reader/android.reader.Reader}: java.lang.NullPointerException
07-10 15:02:15.769: E/AndroidRuntime(3030):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1956)

Comment: 07-10 15:02:15.769: E/AndroidRuntime(3030):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1981)
07-10 15:02:15.769: E/AndroidRuntime(3030):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:123)
07-10 15:02:15.769: E/AndroidRuntime(3030):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1147)
07-10 15:02:15.769: E/AndroidRuntime(3030):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-10 15:02:15.769: E/AndroidRuntime(3030):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)

Comment: 07-10 15:02:15.769: E/AndroidRuntime(3030):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
07-10 15:02:15.769: E/AndroidRuntime(3030):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-10 15:02:15.769: E/AndroidRuntime(3030):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
07-10 15:02:15.769: E/AndroidRuntime(3030):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
07-10 15:02:15.769: E/AndroidRuntime(3030):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)

Comment: 07-10 15:02:15.769: E/AndroidRuntime(3030):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-10 15:02:15.769: E/AndroidRuntime(3030): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
07-10 15:02:15.769: E/AndroidRuntime(3030):  at android.reader.Reader.getNdefMessages(Reader.java:81)
07-10 15:02:15.769: E/AndroidRuntime(3030):  at android.reader.Reader.onCreate(Reader.java:57)
07-10 15:02:15.769: E/AndroidRuntime(3030):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465)

Comment: 07-10 15:02:15.769: E/AndroidRuntime(3030):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
07-10 15:02:15.769: E/AndroidRuntime(3030):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1920)

Comment: It says you have a NullPointerException in line 81 of Reader.java, in the method getNdefMessages().

Comment: so problem comes from the msgs pointer is possible to be null in value, so it cannot be converted into a string?

Comment: By given a value to the msgs, I can successfully launch the program, but it stops then instead of showing the layout I created

Comment: Did you figured it out ?